# How can I verify that a function (IERC777.send) is executed successfully if it doesn't return anything but only emits an event

Tags: require, erc-777, send

In a solidity smart contract function, I want to verify that an IERC777.send function has executed successfully before proceeding. Unfortunately, IERC777 has no bool return that I could use in this way:

```
require(ERC777Token.send(to, amount, ""), "Token send failed.");
```

Similar verification works with ERC20 tokens as the IERC20 transfer function has a bool return implemented:

```
require(ERC20Token.transfer(to, amount), "Token send failed.");
```

So how can I do this verification with IERC777.send?

Part of the contract with the sendTokens example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/IERC777Recipient.sol";   
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/IERC777.sol";   
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/IERC777Sender.sol";   
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC1820Registry.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC1820Implementer.sol";

contract Escrow is IERC777Recipient, IERC777Sender, ERC1820Implementer {

IERC1820Registry private _erc1820 = IERC1820Registry(0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24);
bytes32 constant private TOKENS_RECIPIENT_INTERFACE_HASH = keccak256("ERC777TokensRecipient");
bytes32 constant public TOKENS_SENDER_INTERFACE_HASH = keccak256("ERC777TokensSender");
IERC777 public IERC777Token;

constructor (IERC777 tokenAddress) {
    IERC777Token = IERC777(tokenAddress);
    _erc1820.setInterfaceImplementer(address(this), TOKENS_RECIPIENT_INTERFACE_HASH, address(this));
}

function senderFor(address account) public {
    _registerInterfaceForAddress(TOKENS_SENDER_INTERFACE_HASH, account);
}

event TokensSendDone(address operator, address from, address to, uint256 cost, bytes userData, bytes operatorData);
function tokensToSend(
    address operator,
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 cost,
    bytes memory userData,
    bytes memory operatorData
) public override whenNotPaused {
    emit TokensSendDone(operator, from, to, cost, userData, operatorData);
}

function sendTokens(address to, uint256 amount) public {
    require(ERC777Token.send(to, amount, ""), "Token send failed.");
}
```

}

Comment: How are you deploying this? Localhost or mainnet or testnet?

Comment: mainnet (Polygon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need verification. It either succeeds or the whole transaction will revert. In `ERC20` source code you can see it conveniently returns `True` everytime: [GithubLink](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/a4596cab053d46e0bf2957e2ed490cb3921539ee/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L113-L117). When the `ERC20Token.transfer` failed the transaction will revert and hence all changes are rolled back to before transaction occurs.
You can do the same thing for your ERC777 send.

```
function sendTokens(address to, uint256 amount) public {
    ERC777Token.send(to, amount, ""); // will revert if send failed. 
}
```

If you like to use the same checking boolean mechanism. you can also use [ERC777.transfer](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/a4596cab053d46e0bf2957e2ed490cb3921539ee/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol#L138-L141)

```
function sendTokens(address to, uint256 amount) public {
    require(ERC777Token.transfer(to, amount), "Token send failed.");
}
```

Notes: the mechanism of `send` and `transfer` in `ERC777` maybe different as the last parameter `requireReceptionAck` when they call the internal function `_send` is different. You may need to double check before using transfer.

Comment: Ok, clear. I have to resolve the revert client side then.
 
The IERC777Token.transfer is not available in [IERC777](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/a4596cab053d46e0bf2957e2ed490cb3921539ee/contracts/token/ERC777/IERC777.sol)